# View Bag Not working with HttpPost. How to Use viewBag with httpPost actions?

Tags: viewbag

I have added this action to controller and in View I am displaying

```
<p class="text-success">@ViewBag.result<p />
```

but after I click submit, this viewbag message isn't visible...

```
public ActionResult Contact()
{
    Contact cn = new Contact();
    cn.DateTime = System.DateTime.Now;
    return View(cn);
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Contact(Contact contact)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        ViewBag.result = "Record Inserted Successfully!";
        db.Contacts.Add(contact);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Contact");
    }
    return View(contact);
}
```